# Filter based on model attribute has_many relationship through, rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, has-many-through

I have a simple question, but can't seem to find any solution, though I have found things that are similar, but just not exactly what I am looking for.

I have an application where a User has many Assets through the class UserAsset.  I want to be able to do current_user.user_assets , but I only want to return records that have an Asset with a specified field value of "active".

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753625/filtering-child-objects-in-a-has-many-through-relationship-in-rails-3) is similar but I need to use the main model not the join model as a filter.

```
class UserAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :asset
  belongs_to :user
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_assets
  has_many :users, :through => :user_assets
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_assets
  has_many :assets, :through => :user_assets
end
```

I tried setting the default scope on Asset, and also some conditions on the has many (user_assets) relationship, but rails is failing to consider the join on the Assets table.  ie Unknown column 'asset.live' in 'where clause'. Trying to achieve the following:

```
 @active_user_assets = current_user.user_assets  #only where assets.active = true
```

So how do I use conditions or scopes to achieve this?  I need the user_asset object because it contains info about the relationship that is relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `current_user.assets`, then your scopes should work.

Oh, but you want the user_assets. Hmm. I think you need the `:include` clause to `find()` but where to put it, I can't be arsed to think of right now.

Perhaps

```
current_user.user_assets.find(:all, :include => :assets).where('asset.live=?', true)
```

(I'm not on Rails 3 yet, so that's going to be mangled)

Are you using `:through` when you really want a HABTM?

Comment: I can't use HABTM because I need extra fields on the relationship.  Your tip did help me find the solution though:  I added ":include => :asset,:conditions => "assets.active='1'"" to the "has_many :user_assets" line in User.rb, and now it works perfectly, though I am not positive this is the optimal/proper solution performance wise.  I will give a few minutes to see if someone else has a better idea. Thx